# How to approach user journey mapping for individual personas

Tags: personas, workshop, user-interviews, journey-map

Our UX team maintains a generic user journey map to define the end-to-end travel experience of using our booking app. It was first created during a journey mapping workshop, and over time we have been adding more detailed insights from user interviews into it.

Our customer experience unit has provided us with 5 personas (based on their data) and we would like to create 5 separate user journey maps to match them.

How should we approach this? Should we hold another workshop? Or could we just use the user interview data to create the persona-specific journey maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workshops might not be required in this case, but if they're feasible, they're helpful. Bringing together several people who know something about each customer persona, talking through each experience in detail, can supplement what the customer experience research team has identified.

One approach you might want to explore is [as-is scenario mapping](https://www.ibm.com/design/thinking/page/toolkit/activity/as-is-scenario-map). Prior to the workshop, you'll send out the **current-state** scenarios you'll define together (such as "As a leisure traveler, I want to start exploring the best prices for my upcoming vacation"). You'll share the persona data with the team ahead of the workshop, too, so that everyone will have informed assumptions.

In the workshop, the team will map the scenario using stickies to define what each customer is doing, thinking, and feeling. The link above has more information on the exercise.

[image: As-is scenario map using stickies, from IBM]

You can then use each scenario (as a phase, if it makes sense) to create end-to-end experience maps for each persona, which is helpful because it'll surface the high and low points of the experience in a nice way. There are several examples available online, in varying levels of detail.

[image: Example journey map with high and low emotional points]

Once you've mapped the current state, it becomes easier to brainstorm the future state journey that you'd like to envision.

I recommend reading *UI Is Communication* by Everett N. McKay, which has chapters on personas and journey maps that are coincidentally specific to the travel industry.